# Can Statistics help in reducing row-wise computation time on data.frames?

Tags: r, computational-statistics

I have a data frame with 10,000 rows and 40 columns. I am trying to apply a function to each of these rows. For each row, I am expecting to return a scalar which is the value of the statistic I am calculating in this function. Below is what I have done so far;

```
library(dfadjust)
library(MASS)

# Creating example data #

nrows=10000
ncols=40
n1=20
n2=20
df=data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# Function to evaluate on each row of df #

get_est= function(x){
mod = rlm(x~cov$group)
fit = dfadjustSE(mod)
coef = fit$coefficients[2,1]
se = fit$coefficients[2,4]
stats = coef/se
return(stats)
}

# Applying above function to full data #

t1=Sys.time()
estimates=apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))
t2=Sys.time()-t1

# Time taken by apply function

Time difference of 37.10623 secs
```

Is there a way to significantly decrease the time taken to implement get_est() using some statistical trick given the statistical packages ('rlm' and 'dfadjust') I am using? Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!